# operation overloading with return value (or something like that)

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I have to overload an operator, which goes like this.

```
max(matrix)=11;
```

so, there's a function max, which returns the largest number from that matrix. and this line must set the max value to 11. the question is: how to declare this operator overloading?

Comment: Change the matrix so the new maximum is 11, or change the element that was the max to 11?

Comment: why not using something simpler and clearer like matrix.setMaxLineTo(11) ?

Comment: this does looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Wouldn't he need to overload the int operator=?

Comment: @Ben: Not if `max` returns `int&` or a proxy class.

Comment: Why would int& be any different? EDIT: Yeah, I see how that would work now.

Comment: @aschepler a proxy class would have to overload op= ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There is no operator overloading involved here, except `max(matrix)` should return some user defined type that has overloaded `operator=(int)`, which is not necessary.

What you technically could do to make that line of code work somewhat as you described is returning a (nonconst) reference to the max element of the matrix:

```
int& max(Matrix& mx) { /* ... */ }
```

No operator overloading is required here. The line then would set that element that holds the maximum value to 11. However, after it the max value might not be set to 11. Consider this matrix:

```
/  5  32  10 \
| 11   3  64 |
\ 10   2   0 /
```

clearly the maximum value is 64, but after your line the maximum value would be the 32 in the first row.

However, having a `max` function that does what I described, is not a good idea, because it does not do what one normally expects from such a function. Might be a simple renaming makes it more clear: the standard library uses `max_element` for similar functions, while `max` just returns a maximum value of a collection and does not allow to alter it.

PS: a function making sure that the maximum value of a given matrix is 11 with the syntax you provided is possible but even less intuitive so I won't tempt you by providing a bad example ;-)